# Attribute lost when rendering the object to view in Flask

Tags: python, flask

This is a rather silly issue but I stepped through the function but couldn't figure out what was causing the issue.

I was dynamically adding an attribute to the object I fetched from the db via SQLAlchemy and the objects were appended fine right before the return render_template was called, all but the last appended attribute in the variable from the list of found_survey.questions was lost. I.e. found_survey.questions[0].choices doesn't exist (but it did at one point), but  found_survey.questions[-1].choices does.

I cannot seem to figure out what is going on... I thought it might be funky because of the database object (since I didn't commit survey, but I don't intend to, I was just appending the value so it's passed to the view with the correct logic).

Thanks so much for the help; I'm really stuck...

```
@app.route('/survey/<survey_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def survey(survey_id):
  form = UserSubmitForm()
  found_survey = Survey.query.filter_by(id=survey_id).first()


  if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
    print("input", form.answer_raw.data, form.category_list.data)
    user_answer = Answer(note=found_survey.name,
                         answer_raw=form.answer_raw.data,
                         timestamp=datetime.utcnow(),
                         ip=request.remote_addr)
    user_answer.user_id = g.user.id
    user_answer.survey_id = survey_id
    # other processing omitted
    db.session.add(user_answer)


  elif request.method != "POST":
    for q in found_survey.questions:            
        q.choices = []
        text_list = q.choice_text_string.split(',')
        value_list = q.choice_value_string.split(',')

        for i, text in enumerate(text_list):
           q.choices.append((text, value_list[i]))

    return render_template('survey.html',
                     form=form,
                     survey=found_survey,
                     is_editing=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it just be simpler to do this:

```
annotated_obj = []
for q in found_survey.questions:
    text_list = q.choice_text_string.split(',')
    value_list = q.choice_value_string.split(',')
    question_choices = {}
    for i, text in enumerate(text_list):
       question_choices.setdefault(text, []).append(value_list[i])

    annotated_obj.append((q, question_choices))
```

Comment: The thing is the view renders another block of html based on questions in the survey so I want to just stick the info along with the same object instead of having to pass a separate object (the functionality of Jinja2's templating language is limited), so I want to modify the found_survey object directly